# Simple java date conversion

Tags: java, android, date

Having some troubles and can't find a quick answer..

Im trying to store a date within a string, and later fetch it to convert it back to a date.

However when storing the date using:

```
string tmp = new Date().toString();
```

And then trying to convert it back using

```
Date date = new Date(tmp);
```

I get the Exception type

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

with my Android 2.2 device. Does work with 2.2 & 2.3 emus tho.

Any tips on what other way i can store and convert back?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date Format in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898934/date-format-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with its methods `parse()` and `format()`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String tmp = sdf.format(new Date());
Date date = sdf.parse(tmp);
```

Comment: in what way does this answer add to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898934/date-format-in-android ?

Comment: @evilone It's not the same question. If I had seen that answer, and if that answer had a good detailed explanation on `SimpleDateFormat` involving for instance its non-thread-safe nature, be sure I would have linked to it. And if I had seen at the moment of posting that another fellow beat me to it even if it was by 3 minutes, I would have deleted my answer. Anyway, it was just a question, there's no need for anyone to get mad :-) [Duplicate answers are tolerated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51347/169503), [Dealing with duplicate answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1096/169503).

Comment: @evilone Take it just as a call to improve your question and make it stand over the identical, already existing other. [Do you delete your own answer when it's a duplicate?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15775/169503), and a lot more.

Comment: @XaviLópez Ok, I'm taking your advice to account :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you need it to be a string? long is easier :)

do

```
long time = new Date().getTime();

Date date = new Date(time);
```

then you dont' have to parse

Comment: Will keep it to string since i built it that way but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

// to string
String dateStr = formatter.format(new Date());

// to date 
Date date = formatter.parse(dateStr);
```

Comment: @XaviLópez what is the problem?

Comment: @XaviLópez I wrote the answer when you added yours, so what's the big deal?

Answer (score 0):

use SimpleDateFormat as shown below.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

//this will convert date into string.
String temp = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());

//this will convert string into date format.    
Date date=(Date)formatter.parse(temp);
```