# android date toString

Tags: android

I"m following a tutorial where they have this line:

`int callDate = c.getInt(dateColumn);`

Next, they pass the callDate into the Date object to get a readable format.
But, I think the example may be old, because I get a compile error.

`String myDate = DateUtils.dateString(callDate).toString();`;

So, I'm looking at the API. how do I do it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html

Comment: See the below link. It will definitely help you.

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886516/simple-java-date-conversion/7886622#7886622

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String myString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
```

or

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
mTimeText.setText("Time: " + dateFormat.format(date));
```

Look at [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) and [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for that

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you need to get the date in readable format.In that case you already have the answer you just need to read the link  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html carefully for finding the answer. Let me provide you few hint for the same, see for the constructors on this link for initializing the date of your choice. The methods given helps you perform the operations on it. To answer your question specifically refer below snippet.

```
Date d1=new Date();  //Initializes this Date instance to the current time.
String date= d1.toString(); //this String var date can be used for printing date in readable format
```

the format of string will be "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", which looks something like "Tue Jun 22 13:07:00 PDT 1999".

Comment: SO I would have to do Date d = new Date(callDate); And then dl.toString();

Comment: I assume that 'dateColumn' is the string variable which stores the value for date, you will need to parse  the day, month and year as integers and construct a date object as, 'Date d1=GregorianCalendar(int year,int month,int day);' and then use 'String date =d1.toString();' which will give you the date in human readable format. If you need time to be added please refer other constructors of similar kind listed on the same link I discussed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

See the below link. It will definitely help.

[Simple java date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886516/simple-java-date-conversion/7886622#7886622)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are getting from a Integer
`int callDate = c.getInt(dateColumn);`

the date is a Long type and you're losing precision on this conversion.
try changing to: `long callDate = c.getLong(dateColumn);`